# Does MATE desktop environment use graphics acceleration?

Tags: unity, gnome, graphics, mate, ubuntu-mate

Does MATE desktop environment use graphics acceleration?

I know that Unity uses graphics acceleration, while Xfce doesn't.

The reason I am asking this is because I need as simple as possible interface while being feature rich, to use on few years old laptop, and I do not want it to trigger the GPU because it waste too much battery.

Comment: In MATE Tweak under the option Windows, you can choose between macro (simple desktop effects) and compiz (GPU accelerated effects).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

at the moment **Unity**, **Cinnamon**, **GNOME 3**, **KDE/Plasma** and **LXQt** are using graphic acceleration and **MATE**, **Xfce** and **LXDE** does not (by default).
beside them there are many desktop-environments/window-manager which are mostly less resource hungry than the named ones, but most of them won't be comfortable (for beginners).
so i named only DEs which are easily to get on ubuntu, and if you are thinking about other DEs, i would think about other distributions (specialized for low resources).

---

the other way round: at desktop environments without graphic acceleration you can upgrade shiny desktop effects (with use of graphic acceleration) by changing the window-manager (to **Compiz**, **Composite**, **Compton**):
for example on MATE it is pretty easy... go to the *Control Center* and choose *Desktop Settings*, *Windows* and use the dropdown menu under ***Window Manager***.
[image: Window Manager]

---

"accidentally" i came across an old article, which maybe interesting for your goal: https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=linux_desktop_vitals&num=2
(keep in mind MATE is the successor of GNOME 2)

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu Mate, you can use MATE Tweak (`apt install mate-tweak`) to choose a window manager that uses GPU acceleration, like Compton or Compiz.

This is a screenshot of the window managers available by default on Ubuntu Mate 16.04 LTS, 18.04 LTS (and newer); *Marco (Compton GPU compositor)* and *Compiz (Advanced GPU accelerated desktop effects)*
 use GPU acceleration:

[image: Window managers available on Ubuntu Mate 18]